# Different views on router.php (Joomla! 3.6.4)

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, sef, custom-module, jroute

I am developing my second custom component for Joomla! 3.6.4 and I have another problem with my `router.php`. This time I need to dynamically change the view on my `router.php` but I don’t know how to do it. On my component, I have four different views, each one of them with a different name, of course. So, I have:

1. View-1 list and View-1 single
2. View-2 list and View-2 single
3. View-3 list and View-3 single
4. View-4 list and View-4 single

The problem with my `router.php` is that I don’t know how to dynamically change the view on the variable `$vars['view'] = "VIEW";`. The other problem is that I call the component’s links from a module outside a Menu Item, so it is all really complex. However, my question is: How can I pull the view dynamically and then populate the `$vars['view']`?

Here is my `router.php`:

```
class ComponentNameRouter extends JComponentRouterBase
{
    /**
     * Build method for URLs
     * This method is meant to transform the query parameters into a more human
     * readable form. It is only executed when SEF mode is switched on.
     *
     * @param   array  &$query  An array of URL arguments
     *
     * @return  array  The URL arguments to use to assemble the subsequent URL.
     *
     * @since   3.3
     */
    public function build(&$query)
    {
        $segments = array();

        if (isset($query['view'])) {
            unset($query['view']);
        } 

        if(isset($query['id']) && isset($query['name']))                               
        {
            $segments[] = $query['id']."-".$query['name'];
            unset($query['id']);
            unset($query['name']);  
        }
        else if(isset($query['id']))                               
        {
            $segments[] = $query['id'];
            unset($query['id']);
        }
        return $segments;
    }

    /**
     * Parse method for URLs
     * This method is meant to transform the human readable URL back into
     * query parameters. It is only executed when SEF mode is switched on.
     *
     * @param   array  &$segments  The segments of the URL to parse.
     *
     * @return  array  The URL attributes to be used by the application.
     *
     * @since   3.3
     */
    public function parse(&$segments)
    {
        $vars = array();
        $vars['view'] = "name-of-ONE-of-the-view";    
        $aux = explode(":",$segments[0]);     
        $vars['id'] = $aux[0];    
        return $vars;
    }
}
```

*P.S.* Since the name of the views are the same as the parameters I use to change the module layouts, I tried to access the params and then echo the current one on `$vars['view']` but it did not work, unfortunately.

Comment: Please provide a var_dump of your $segments array.

Comment: And please take a look into https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component  / in Joomla 3.8 (should update to that version) we have a new router class.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thank you very much for your reply.
The var_dump of my $segments array is: array(1) { [0]=> string(X) "name-of-the-view/id-name" } .
For example: array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "player/56-alexandor-vandemar" } .

Unfortunately, I can't update Joomla! to the 3.8 version because of corporate's choices, but they are working on that.

Comment: Did you try the router from my answer? I really don't get, as far as I could see, you just need to use a standard router and valid views in your component. Sometimes it helps if you turn off SEF in Joomla config to see the parameter url for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this on my older J3 components:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class MyComponentRouter extends JComponentRouterBase
{
    /**
     * Build method for URLs
     * This method is meant to transform the query parameters into a more human
     * readable form. It is only executed when SEF mode is switched on.
     *
     * @param   array  &$query  An array of URL arguments
     *
     * @return  array  The URL arguments to use to assemble the subsequent URL.
     *
     * @since   3.3
     */
    public function build(&$query)
    {
        $segments = array();
        $view     = null;

        if (isset($query['task']))
        {
            $taskParts  = explode('.', $query['task']);
            $segments[] = implode('/', $taskParts);
            $view       = $taskParts[0];
            unset($query['task']);
        }

        if (isset($query['view']))
        {
            $segments[] = $query['view'];
            $view       = $query['view'];
            unset($query['view']);
        }

        if (isset($query['id']))
        {
            if ($view !== null)
            {
                $segments[] = $query['id'];
            }
            else
            {
                $segments[] = $query['id'];
            }

            unset($query['id']);
        }

        return $segments;
    }

    /**
     * Parse method for URLs
     * This method is meant to transform the human readable URL back into
     * query parameters. It is only executed when SEF mode is switched on.
     *
     * @param   array  &$segments  The segments of the URL to parse.
     *
     * @return  array  The URL attributes to be used by the application.
     *
     * @since   3.3
     */
    public function parse(&$segments)
    {
        $vars = array();

        // View is always the first element of the array
        $vars['view'] = array_shift($segments);

        while (!empty($segments))
        {
            $segment = array_pop($segments);

            // If it's the ID, let's put on the request
            if (is_numeric($segment))
            {
                $vars['id'] = $segment;
            }
            else
            {
                $vars['task'] = $vars['view'] . '.' . $segment;
            }
        }

        return $vars;
    }
}
```